# rmi4_physical rmi4-00:Failed to read irqs, code=-6 error

Tags: boot, restart

this error show "rmi4_physical rmi4-00:Failed to read irqs, code=-6 error" if i restart my Computer.
laptop is hp 15-ay008tx.
ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: I'm having the same error on my new ThinkPad P14s with Ubuntu 21.04. Have you found anything related on this?